# How to exclude one window title from taskkill command?

Tags: cmd, autoit

I want to terminate a process but one window title should be excluded. So in a browser every window gets killed except the one I want to stay open.

```
taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq windowtitle" = exclusion
```

The reason is if I use :

```
Run(@ComSpec & ' /c start msedge --inprivate --window-size=100,100 --window-position=955,535 --app="url',@SW_HIDE)
```

AutoIt opens an extra new tab window sometimes (and that's why I want to close each instance except the one I call here). Because the window title (new tab) is specified in local language, I want to have it so that it works for different countries

How can I can accomplish that with a batch file or in AutoIt or anything else?

Comment: Unless I've completely misunderstood your question, have you tried using the `ne` operator with a `WINDOWTITLE` `/FI`lter?

Comment: dont worked for me so both solutions but it works now  without cmd taskkill .. thanks anyways

Comment: Use command like this: `taskkill  /fi "windowtitle ne url*" /im msedge.exe`.
But if you cannot find your window by window title there is another way. Run process. Save it's Id in environment variable. Than kill all `msedge.exe" except this Id.